# Is it possible to accelerate clang-tidy using ccache or similar?

Tags: c++, c, static-analysis, clang-tidy, ccache

Since employing `ccache` on our CI server, we find that the bottleneck in terms of build time is now our static analysis pass, that uses `clang-tidy`, among other tools. Does anyone know of a way to accelerate `clang-tidy` in a similar way to how `ccache` does so with a regular compiler?

Comment: try to tidy only modified files, https://clang.llvm.org/extra/doxygen/clang-tidy-diff_8py_source.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the question and everybody for the answers.

After struggling to make [ejfitzgerald/clang-tidy-cache](https://github.com/ejfitzgerald/clang-tidy-cache) working w/o any decent documentation or help I've given a try [matus-chochlik/ctcache](https://github.com/matus-chochlik/ctcache). It's indeed much easier in installation and configuration.

Here's a snippet we use to automatically use it with cmake when it's installed

```
find_program (CLANG_TIDY_CACHE_PATH NAMES "clang-tidy-cache")
if (CLANG_TIDY_CACHE_PATH)
    find_program (_CLANG_TIDY_PATH NAMES "clang-tidy" "clang-tidy-15" "clang-tidy-14" "clang-tidy-13" "clang-tidy-12")

    # Why do we use ';' here?
    # It's a cmake black magic: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CLANG_TIDY.html#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_CLANG_TIDY
    # The CLANG_TIDY_PATH is passed to CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY, which follows CXX_CLANG_TIDY syntax.
    set (CLANG_TIDY_PATH "${CLANG_TIDY_CACHE_PATH};${_CLANG_TIDY_PATH}" CACHE STRING "A combined command to run clang-tidy with caching wrapper")
else ()
    find_program (CLANG_TIDY_PATH NAMES "clang-tidy" "clang-tidy-15" "clang-tidy-14" "clang-tidy-13" "clang-tidy-12")
endif ()

set (CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_PATH}")
```

With it, if `clang-tidy-cache` is in the path, it will be used together with any found `clang-tidy`.

During the build, we define `CTCACHE_DIR` and preserve them between builds.

In our [CI](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/42913/files) it caused reducing the linting time from 330 minutes to 22, so it's almost 15x faster!

Comment: ctcache does indeed seem like the best solution. Since your posting I have got a few PRs committed upstream to fix various wrinkles I was experiencing. One issue remains for me: when there is a cache hit, the output of clang-tidy is not reproduced. Since I parse the output of clang-tidy in order to track changes over time, this would mean that warnings would spuriously disappear/reappear depending on their cache status. I have fixed this in my fork https://github.com/timangus/ctcache, albeit only for the local backend. Any contributions to fix the other backends are welcome, then I'll PR it.

Comment: @TimAngus - looks like it got support for stdout caching in [a10ce62b](https://github.com/timangus/ctcache/commit/a10ce62b6d237bcdd531f08a8fa9401a28640573).

Comment: @Zitrax oh yeah! Seems like it needs the environment variable CTCACHE_SAVE_OUTPUT set to 1 to work. Not sure why that isn't the default...

Answer (score 4):

I found another important detail here:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/1791/diffs

which is used here:

https://reviews.bitcoinabc.org/D5150?id=15995

So in order to be able to cache the output of the compiler when integrating clang-tidy using the :
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY ...

method you need to use the COMPILER_LAUNCHER method to configure ccache

```
find_program(CCACHE ccache)
if(CCACHE)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER ${CCACHE})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER ${CCACHE})
endif(CCACHE)
```

and NOT the launcher rule method:

```
find_program(CCACHE ccache)
if(CCACHE)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE ${CCACHE})
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_LINK ${CCACHE})
endif(CCACHE)
```

Comment: The problem here is generally in the fact that clang-tidy does not compile, so ccache doesn't work with it. See the comment https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/42190#issuecomment-1288781217

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get clang-tidy-cache to build because I didn't have the correct go version, so I made [cltcache](https://github.com/freedick/cltcache) in python instead. It is meant to be used exactly like ccache and is hopefully a lot easier to install than clang-tidy-cache.

It will hash the preprocessor output with comments along with the enabled checks and the clang-tidy-version string and use that as the key for the cache. Upon cache miss it will ä do the clang-tidy call and compress and store the stdout, the stderr and the return code in the cache.

Not sure if it is fast enough for other projects but in my project, clang-tidy consumes around 4x as much time as the actual compilation, so running a preprocessor an extra time consumes a comparatively negligible amount of time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

There is [clang-tidy-cache](https://github.com/ejfitzgerald/clang-tidy-cache) although i don't know how that works together with ccache.

Comment: That looks promising... I'll give it a look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a solution for this: it's switching the build system to [bazel](https://bazel.build/). bazel is a build system which is very generic and defines an action graph. Essentially every action has a set of inputs and outputs. Based on the inputs the outputs can be cached. Hence, bazel solves the problem at it's root.

The necessary rules for integrating clang-tidy in a cachable way can be found here: https://github.com/erenon/bazel_clang_tidy

In order to make use of caching you need to setup a [remote cache](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/remote-caching.html). This can be done using a docker-compose script. The necessary docker container already exists. The command to get it running can be found here: https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote/

Finally, bazel also solves the problem of caching the result of the linking phase.

Not only that but bazel also allows building other languages like java. Hence, in complex projects it allows to replace all other build system with a single one.

Finally, bazel also allows parallelizing your build on a cluster.

Last but not least you can define several [platforms](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/platforms.html) and [toolchains](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/toolchains.html). All in all this allows to do cross-platform builds.

Comment: Good solution if you're using bazel I guess, thanks.

Comment: bazel may be ok for in-house projects, but what about interfacing with the rest of the world ?

Comment: Bazel can integrate external, non bazel projects as described here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.18.1/external.html#:~:text=Bazel%20can%20depend%20on%20targets,files%20with%20their%20own%20targets. Basically you provide your own bazel file and check it into your repo. You instruct bazel to overlay that build file on the external project. I have done this for simdjson and rapidjson and it was easy to do - I'm of course not building the tests etc...